# Установка пакета python-dev в cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin

При разворачивании проекта на cygwin получил ошибку

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Для debian-подобных систем она решается установкой python-dev

Команда для cygwin

```
apt-cyg install python-dev
```

возвращает Unable locate package.
Попытка изменить зеркало для Cygwin (из приведенного списка https://cygwin.com/mirrors.html)

```
apt-cyg -m update <mirror>
```

возвращает 404 ошибку. 
Как решить указанную проблему?

Comment: Попробуйте для установки пакетов Cygwin использовать штатную утилиту setup-x86*.exe с [официального сайта](https://cygwin.com/).

Comment: Судя по `setup.ini`, такого пакета в Cygwin нет.

Comment: Да, все верно пакета нет. Пакеты устанавливаются в запуске установщика из списка выбранных репозиториев